# Algorithm to get maximum affordable amount of items with individual costs and limits

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

i got a small headache over a problem regarding an efficient way to distribute a fixed amount of points evenly between n items that got different costs and limits. Costs *don't* increase with each item.

Lets say i got 3 Items:

| Name | Cost | Limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25 | 220 |
| B | 30 | 20 |
| C | 50 | 60 |

Further we got fixed Points: **5000**.
I want to know how many times i can buy each.
My curent solution runs a loop and deducts the cost from points until either all limits are reached or  points ran out.
http://jsfiddle.net/nasc8rfL/

```
var points = 5000;
var costA = 25;
var costB = 30;
...

var limitA = 220;
...

var maxA = 0;

while (points > 0){
   if (points >= costA && limitA > 0){
     points -=costA;
     limitA -=1;
     maxA +=1;
   };
   if (points >= costB && limitB > 0){
     points -=costB;
     limitB -=1;
     maxB +=1;
   };
   if (points >= costC && limitC > 0){
     points -=costC;
     limitC -=1;
     maxC +=1;
   };
   if((points < costA) and (points < costB) and (points <costC)) break; 
}    

console.log(maxA,maxB,maxC);
```

Eventually it will not stay at A,B,C but variable number of elements(not more than 20) so i'd loop through each element instead of 3 IFs.

I dont actually have to deduct points i just have to know how many of each item can be bought. I feel like im missing something and there is an easier way to determine the number of each.

I've thought about weighting them based on their limits but my head doesnt want to work with me and im pretty stuck right now.

In addition im a beginner in javascript, so if you guys got some tips to get the shown loop faster or more convinient maybe with something like

```
function func(arr){
  arr.forEach(x=>{doSomething();})
```

i would be more than happy.

Comment: Might be a [linear optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). Do you have a preference what to buy first `A`, `B` or `C` or what would be an optimal solution? If it was a linear optimization you would need some function to optimize and a **profit** for each option. Or do you just want to divide the 5000 so that most that ideally all of those 5000 points are used?

Comment: When you say you want to divide the evenly, does that mean you want to buy one of each, then two of each, etc., until you run out of money (or hit the purchase limit)?

Comment: Do you need to minimise the leftover amount (i.e. come as close to 5000 as possible)?

Comment: To answer youtr questions: @Mushroomator
No, i will have a sorted list and buy one after another using up the points with no special optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach isn't bad. The algorithm can be sped up a bit by

- keeping the elements in a list, and not just visiting each during each iteration of your outer loop, but by kicking it out of the list once it hit its limit
- not just buying one of each item per round, but as many as feasible if you'd by equally many of each while staying within budget.

```js
const points = 5000;
const items = [
  {name: "A", cost: 25, limit: 220},
  {name: "B", cost: 30, limit: 60},
  {name: "C", cost: 50, limit: 20},
];
let amounts = Object.fromEntries(items.map(i => [i.name, 0]));
let available = items;
let toSpend = points;
do {
  available = available.filter(i => amounts[i.name] < i.limit && i.cost <= toSpend);
  const maxAmount = Math.max(1, Math.floor(toSpend / available.reduce((s, i) => s+i.cost, 0)));
  for (const a of available) {
    const amount = Math.min(maxAmount, a.limit - amounts[a.name]);
    if (amount * a.cost <= toSpend) {
      amounts[a.name] += amount;
      toSpend -= amount * a.cost;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
} while (available.length);
console.log(amounts);
console.log(`Leftover: ${toSpend}`);
```